# What is the symbol for bitwise negation?

Tags: notation

Which symbol is used for bitwise negation? Eg:

```
{some_symbol} 0 = 1
{some_symbol} 1 = 0

{some_symbol} 10 = 01
{some_symbol} 01 = 10
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more appropriate for some programming language website, but the standard symbol for bitwise negation in C and languages with C-like syntax is the tilde symbol ~.  I don't think there's a standard in mathematics; if you need it in a math paper, just define what you want clearly and then use it.